# How to re-use shared library from another package to compile a new package in yocto?

Tags: linux, yocto

I want to add new package to yocto that is depend on other package (composed by library so file and binary) that I get it from git. The new package must use the shared library from old package to build it.

The source code of old library must centralized in one place and all package (project) just use it if needed.

How can I build my package without changing my old package?

Can I get two source from git in bb file and after that compile them by order library and new application? if yes how?

I tried to search that but I haven't found any persistant result.

**Example:**

- package1.bb => build and generate a package that contain binary and so lib.
- package2.bb => build a new package using the library of package1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to build a package that is depending on another package (the library in this case).

My suggestion would be to first create a package of the library (in a separate .bb file) and then using the DEPENDS and RDEPENDS flags in the other project to make sure your build system is aware of the dependency.

Comment: yes I want to compile my package using the library generated of another package, how can I force my package see the library?

Comment: I mean I want to add -lotherpacakge in my makefile and I want to pass library path in LDFLAG

Comment: if add a new package to generate a library from package1, how to pass it to package for compiling it and installing as dependency? `DEPENDS` and `RDEPENDS` flags can do that? how?

Comment: DEPENDS list the build-time dependencies of a package. If you add a package (package1 in this case) to this list, the files contained in that package will be extracted when building package2. Please see the reference on the yocto webpage (http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-DEPENDS).

RDEPENDS list the runtime dependencies of a package.

I can recommend you to check how this is done in other recipes to get the basic idea.

Comment: thanks for your help, it works when I create another package for the lib and I have used DEPENDS in bb file of my package

Comment: Great, if it is a run-time dependency don't forget to add it to the RDEPENDS list (as this will pull in the package to your system if you forget to add it in your image .bb file).